# Assignment with OR operator

Tags: c++, c++11, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

So I came across this code when I was reading source code in Github.

```
addr2int = ( (uint32_t)paddr[2] ) | ( (uint32_t)paddr[3] << 8 ) | ( (uint32_t)paddr[4] << 16 ) | ( (uint32_t)paddr[5] << 24 )
```

Can someone explain to me what happens here?

As far as I can tell this is an assignment but I don't understand why there are `|` operators, or whether this is an multiple assignment.

Comment: Have a look in the section [bitwise logic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: The comment above answers your question: you are confused by bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `(uint32_t)paddr[2] ) | ( (uint32_t)paddr[3] << 8 ) | (
>   (uint32_t)paddr[4] << 16 ) | ( (uint32_t)paddr[5] << 24 )`

1. It's basically bitwise OR (operator `|`) of four integers.
2. Secondly, consider this: `(uint32_t)paddr[2]`. Here we tell the compiler to cast whatever is inside `paddr[2]` into an `unsigned long int`, where `uint32_t` is [c++11 std](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). Nevertheless `(uint32_t)variable` is a C-style casting. In modern C++11, you can write it as `static_cast<uint32_t>paddr[2]`.
3. Thirdly, `variable_x << variable_y` is a bitwise left shift. Read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/336xbhcz.aspx) with an example.

Comment: But is only one variable being assigned here? because i find it pretty strange that some one does 4 operations in one line for an assignment hmm

Comment: @user3244534 The four things are combined with bitwise OR and assigned to the variable.